# Multiple uses of SaveAs freezes Excel

Tags: excel, vba, save

I am working with a large file that includes data across multiple (100+) clients.

Needs:

- Generate monthly summary of client activity.
- Must be in an Excel manipulatable format.
- Must be client specific. No access to other's information.

My process works, but it hangs and can take anywhere between 10 - 45 minutes.

After troubleshooting I know the issue is with the SaveAs method. Commenting said line out and still allowing files to be generated and closed does not cause the hang ups.

```vb
For i = 1 to Number_of_clients

    'Data is sorted and placed in report tab (not shown)

    'Code ensures only report tab is saved with no access to other data
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Filename
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Next i
```

My current attempts to alleviate this issue is to pause the application so background processes can do their thing. I included the following code after the SaveAs line.

```
Application.Wait (Now + Timevalue("0:00:05"))
```

Comment: You might be able to get away from 'stalling' the cycle if you reference the workbooks/worksheets directly whenever possible and stay away from using the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). The [ActiveWorkbook property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821871.aspx) may be necessary to reference the new workbook created when copying a worksheet to no location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "...pause the application so background processes can do their thing."

Have you tried `DoEvents` ?

This surrenders control back to the operating system and allows it to complete any pending events before code execution resumes. If you are in a loop that's locking up you should definitely use this just so that you can manually break code execution.

---

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Filename
DoEvents
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
```

---

More information: [DoEvents in VBA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/118468)

Comment: I owe you a beer. That did exactly what was needed. No freeze, no hang, smooth running.

Comment: No worries. Don't forget to accept as the answer if it worked by ticking the green tick to the left of the post :)